# Transform data by grouping column value then getting all its grouped data using Panda DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, dictionary

I got this structure of data from csv file.

```
string       | group  |    datetime 
some_string1   apple     2023-09-20 17:20:19
some_string2   apple     2023-09-25 17:20:19
some_string3   apple     2023-09-21 17:20:19
some_string4   banana    2023-09-23 17:20:19
some_string5   cherry    2023-09-23 17:20:19
some_string6   apple     2023-09-22 17:20:19
```

I want to transform this into:

```
                        apple                |                     banana                        |              cherry           

datetime             |          string       |      datetime             |          string       |       datetime       |        string   

2023-09-20 17:20:19       some_string1             2023-09-23 17:20:19           some_string4       2023-09-23 17:20:19      some_string5
2023-09-21 17:20:19       some_string3             somedatime                    some_string(n)        somedatime            some_string(n)
2023-09-22 17:20:19       some_string6             somedatime                    some_string(n)        somedatime            some_string(n)
2023-09-25 17:20:19       some_string2             somedatime                    some_string(n)        somedatime            some_string(n)
```

As you can see above there it is grouped by values from column **group** then have subcolumn datetime and string.

I have already got the headers(its not perfect but workable) using this snippet but I'm blocked with assigning the values into each columns. Note that all grouped value from fruits column should be a new column.

```
    data = {}
    headers = []

    with open(r'somecsv.csv') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

        for n, row in enumerate(reader):
            if not n:
                # Skip header row (n = 0).
                continue  
            string, fruits, datetime = row
            if fruits not in data:
                data[fruits] = list()
                data[fruits].append((datetime, string))
            # print(datetime)
            if fruits not in headers:
                headers.append(fruits)

    cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([headers, ['datetime', 'string']])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
    df.to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

this does create a csv with headers and subcolumn but no values below it. I'm already blocked and needed some help. Thank you

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input and the exact matching expected output, images are not reproducible and ambiguous

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: Sorry. Got hard time to create a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with counter and [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for final DataFrame, last for necessary ordering use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'somecsv.csv')

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['fruits'].unique(), ['datetime', 'string']])

out = (df.melt('fruits')
        .assign(g = lambda x: x.groupby(['fruits','variable']).cumcount())
        .pivot(index='g', columns=['fruits','variable'], values='value')
        .reindex(columns, axis=1)
        .rename_axis(None))

out.to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, Is it also possible if I can sort the values asc by its datetime?

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB - Can you add some data sample and expected ouput to question? thanks.

Comment: Hi @jezrael, i modified the table on my question. as you can see on the apple column, it is sorted by its datetime ascending.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB - Can you test if use `df = pd.read_csv(r'somecsv.csv')` and then  `df = df.sort_values(['fruits','datetime'])` if working like need?

Comment: It works as needed! Thanks a lot! I'm just new with Pandas there's a lot more I need to learn. Thanks again so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

u can try this :

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv

data = {}
with open('somecsv.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader)  # Skip the header row
    for row in reader:
        string, fruits, datetime = row
        if fruits not in data:
            data[fruits] = {'datetime': [], 'string': []}
        data[fruits]['datetime'].append(datetime)
        data[fruits]['string'].append(string)

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list(data.keys()), ['datetime', 'string']])
df_data = {col: data[col[0]][col[1]] for col in columns}
df = pd.DataFrame(df_data, columns=columns)

df.to_csv('output_file.csv', index=False)
```